# Groovy: how to reference a variable?

Tags: java, groovy, groovy-console

How to reference the variable inside the map .
When I do this I only get literal string dcihub_sonar_binaries, while I expect the else rule to result to value of dcihub_sonar_binaries.

```
  dcihub_sonar_binaries = '$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.apps/target/,$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.config/target/,$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.content/target/'
def CODEBASE = "dcihub"
    def SonarValues = [:]
    if (CODEBASE == "platform") {
        SonarValues = ["platform": [platform_sonar_exclusion, platform_sonar_binaries]]

    } else {
        SonarValues.put(CODEBASE, "${CODEBASE}_sonar_binaries")
    }
    return SonarValues
}
```

When I print it. That is the ouput.

```
dcihub_sonar_binaries
```

Expected output :

`'$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.apps/target/,$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.config/target/,$WORKSPACE/tenants/dcihub/ui.content/target/`'

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how/where variable is declared.

If it's a local variable inside function/method then no way to reference it - think about storing all required values in map.

If it's a script/object variable/property then this should work:

```
this."${CODEBASE}_sonar_binaries"
```

Instead of `this` there could be any object where the variable/property is declared.

For example this script prints `Hello world!`

```
hello_world="Hello world!"
def suffix = 'world'
println this."hello_${suffix}"
```

But this fails because hello_world will be a part of hidden `run()` function:

```
def hello_world="Hello world!"
def suffix = 'world'
println this."hello_${suffix}"
```